# C Program using a function to round a floating- point number to 3 digits after the decimal?

Tags: c, math, rounding

An example would be if input is 3456.7856, then the output should be 3456.786.

Thank you so much and have a blessed day!

Comment: Please read [the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [*How do I ask a good question?*](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: You don't do that for your variables, you do that when formatting your output with [`printf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf).

Comment: Do you want to round the output, or assign a rounded value to a variable?

Comment: `round_x = round(x * 1000.0) / 1000.0;` The result probably won't be exact due to most floating point implementations not being able to represent decimal fractions exactly.

Answer (score 2):

A standard library function called [`printf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf) can do the rounding:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int
main(void) {
    double dbl = 3456.7856;
    printf("%.3f", dbl);
}
```

In case you want to use the rounded value in some computation:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <float.h>
#include <math.h>

double
round_to_3(double dbl);

int
main(void) {
    double dbl = 3456.7856, dummy; // dummy will hold the integral part of dbl
                                   // , which we won't use

    if(modf(dbl, &dummy)) {
        dbl = round_to_3(dbl);
    }

    // Do some computation

    printf("%.3f", dbl);
}

double
round_to_3(double dbl) {
    char buffer[1 + 1 + DBL_MAX_10_EXP + 1 + 3 + 1]; 
    // Making sure the buffer is big enough:
    //
    // 1 for the potential sign
    // plus 1 for the leading digit
    // plus DBL_MAX_10_EXP for the potential digits before the decimal mark
    // plus 1 for the decimal mark
    // plus 3 for the digits after the decimal mark
    // plus 1 for the ending '\0'

    sprintf(buffer, "%.3f", dbl);
    sscanf(buffer, "%lf", &dbl);

    return dbl;
}
```

This solution seems weird, but it won't cause overflow, and provides maximum accuracy.

You don't need to do the rounding when `modf(dbl, &intpart) == 0`, because usually the significant is very small compared to `base ^ exponent`, namely `10 ^ DBL_MAX_10_EXP` in this case.(here, `^` means exponentiation, other than bitwise XOR)